# Thread Abort error : response.end leads to error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery post method in my form and submiting my response to the UI by using response.end event but whenever I execute that line it result to an error

> "Thread abort error"

I have seen lots of post on stackoverflow.com abt the same issue but no one has posted possible solution for this error. Everytime I send response to the front end it result to an error.

any comments will be apprecriated.

Comment: check that response in fiddler or firebug, may be your response is incomplete

Comment: That exception happens sometimes when you use `Response.End()`. The only thing you can do is to not wrap it in try block, or use another logic for your app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well.. I solved the error in this way... Well I was calling a separate page from jquery post method.

I deleted all the HTML + DocType which was in my separate aspx page only thing i kept was page directive code and thats it... nothing more.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableTheming="false" StylesheetTheme="" Theme="" EnableEventValidation="false"
 CodeFile="Approval_API.aspx.cs" Inherits="API_Approval_API" %>
```

Also in my code behind : I removed Response.end and just wrote this line

```
var vjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objPageRespone, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(vjson);
```

I don't know whether this will work for Response.Redirect scenario but it worked for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Response.End() method stop processing the script and return the current result, it will not process any further processing at server end. 
Please check your console and check your response what is returning, it is better to add all the required response headers and content before flushing response.